# Read class objects directly into a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

So I've started learning vectors in c++, and I made this program, but I dont like the fact that I read the object data into a *C style* array, and then I transfer all the data into a vector.
Is it possible to read the data into the vector, without using the *C style* array?
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

class number
{
private:
    std::string name;
    float n1_;
    int n2_;

public:
    number() = default;
    ~number() = default;

public:
    void read();
    float perMonth(){return n1_ * n2_;}
    float perYear(){return perMonth() * 12;}
    std::string get_Name(){return name;}
};

void number::read()
{
    cout << "Worker name: "; cin >> name;
    n1_ = rand() % 100 + 3;
    n2_ = rand() % 100 + 3;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Insert number of workers:"; cin >> n;

    number pers[30];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        pers[i].read();

    std::vector<number> people;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        people.push_back(pers[i]);

    for(number pr : people)
    {
        cout << "Name: " << pr.get_Name() << endl;
        cout << "Salary per month: " << pr.perMonth() << endl;
        cout << "Salary per year: " << pr.perYear() << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: [`std::vector<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) has various options to do that. There's `push_back()`, `emplace_back()` or the possibility to allocate for `n` times `T` in advance at construction. So clarify a bit mor why you're using a raw array in 1st place please.

Comment: I used the C style array because I tried to access the ```number::read()``` method, didnt know how to call it from a vector

Comment: _"didnt know how to call it from a vector"_ Dereferencing `vec[i].read()`, just like you'd do with a c-style array.

Comment: ou... that simple... thanks!

Comment: You'll need a valid element at index `i` to do that of course. Another possibility is to use a local variable `Person p;` in a loop, doing `p.read()` and `people.push_back(p);` reapeatedly.

Comment: got it, I managed to make it work with a for loop, using i. All the articles about vectors look so complicated... thanks for showing me how easy it could be

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

class number
{
private:
    std::string name;
    float n1_;
    int n2_;

public:
    number() = default;
    ~number() = default;

public:
    void read();
    float perMonth(){return n1_ * n2_;}
    float perYear(){return perMonth() * 12;}
    std::string get_Name(){return name;}
};

void number::read()
{
    cout << "Worker name: "; cin >> name;
    n1_ = rand() % 100 + 3;
    n2_ = rand() % 100 + 3;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Insert number of workers:"; cin >> n;

    std::vector<number> people(n);

    //N.B that pr is a non const reference in this loop
    for(number& pr : people){
       pr.read();
    }

    for(number pr : people)
    {
        cout << "Name: " << pr.get_Name() << endl;
        cout << "Salary per month: " << pr.perMonth() << endl;
        cout << "Salary per year: " << pr.perYear() << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You can put objects into std::vector without using an array.

```
    int main()
    {
        int n;
        cout << "Introduceti numarul de lucratori:"; cin >> n;
    
        std::vector<number> people;
    
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            number pers();
            pers.read();
            people.push_back(per);
        }
    
        for(number pr : people)
        {
            cout << "Name: " << pr.get_Name() << endl;
            cout << "Salary per month: " << pr.perMonth() << endl;
            cout << "Salary per year: " << pr.perYear() << endl << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mind to elaborate how exactly, and which technique should be used for which specific use case and why?

Comment: The question is "Can we add object directly in to std::vector (without using an array)?". The answer is "YES" and showed how to add objects directly in to the std::vector.